# Nested EventListner looking for content loaded?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to detect when a `div` within the entire document is loaded.

but for some reason is this not being detected?

https://codepen.io/noflaco/pen/eoeexM?editors=1111

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const test = document.getElementById("test");
  function consent() {
    alert("test");
  }
  test.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", Consent);
});
```

why not?

Comment: You don't have to wait for a div to load to use it. `"DOMContentLoaded"` is for the entire dom to load.

Answer (score 0):

> why not?

Arbitrary DOM elements to not trigger a `DOMContentLoaded` event, so the event handler is never executed. This event is only triggered on the `document` element when whole DOM has been parsed and loaded.

[You can learn more about this event on MDN](http://DOMContentLoaded).

---

Ironically, the fact that you can load the div via `document.getElementById("test")` means that it already exists, so there is no point in adding a handler to wait for it to load.

Comment: so what do you suggest?

Comment: Identify the logic that dynamically creates the element you are concerned with.  One you do that, it narrows down how to proceed.

Comment: @IamnotFat: Depends in what you want to do. Just use `test` since it exists. If you want to do something with the `<div>` before the whole document loaded, but a `<script>` just after the `<div>`.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the answer. 
I have to add  an eventlistner, and the id connected to another script, that loads an application, hence i need to add the eventlistner once content is loaded, or at least test in document.

Comment: @IamnotFat: I'm not sure what that means. Are you saying that there is other JavaScript that creates the element with ID `test` dynamically and you want to know when it was created?

Comment: Test is an unique ID, but is used by an different script, which renders a an third party application... I just want to apply something after all JavaScript has been rendered, and application is on.. but doing it nested doesn't seem to be possible? so how should I do it?

Comment: If you mean that some other code adds elements to `test` and you want  to know when the other code is done, then there is no general solution. Maybe the third-party code provides a way to notify you when it is done, e.g. by allowing you to register a callback.